How to make text shrink to fit parent composable width
ClickableSurface(
    onClick = onClick,
    modifier = modifier
        .height(labelHeight.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
){
    Box(
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = text,
            style = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 8.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium,
                color = color100
            ),
            maxLines = 1,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
        )
    }
}

The default fontSize is 8.dp, I want to make the fontSize responsive such that if the characters in text can't fit a single line, fontSize should reduce till the text fits.

Text composable has onTextLayout argument - a callback that is executed when a new text layout is calculated. It gives you an instance of TextLayoutResult which you can use to find out if your text fits or not and update the font size accordingly.
var fontSize by remember {
  mutableStateOf(8.sp)
}

Text(
  text = text,
  maxLines = 1,
  fontSize = fontSize,
  onTextLayout = {
    if (it.didOverflowWidth) {
      fontSize = fontSize * .9F
    }
  }
)


not sure why, butit.didOverflowHeight did the trick.
